# keeping audio visualizations on in vlc

Tags: vlc

Every time I select an audio visualization in vlc for audio files, it is forgotten after restarting vlc and no visualization is shown.

Is there a way to keep audio visualizations on in vlc?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that VLC is for some reason ignoring the config file or recreating it?

What I'm finding is that the config file is setup per user and the below location would be where one could find the file. I'm curious if perhaps that file is getting recreated every time?

Linux / Unix: $(HOME)/.config/vlc/vlcrc (v0.9.0 and above), $(HOME)/.vlc/vlcrc (v0.8 and older)

Source: https://www.videolan.org/support/faq.html#Config

Comment: it seems nothing in the config file is about on or off visualizations.